# XAMPP VirtualHost Redirects to htdocs

Tags: apache, xampp

I have reviewed a number of answers on this topic but non of them helped. I am trying to set multiple virtual hosts in XAMPP but once I type server alias into browser it redirects me to XAMPP/dashboard. Could you please take a look the code below and share your thought. Thanks in advance.

httpd-vhosts.conf file

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
  ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost test*:80>
    DocumentRoot "E:/Drive/Dev/test"
    ServerName test
    ServerAlias test
    <Directory "E:/Drive/Dev/test">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

httpd.conf file

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

hosts file

```
127.0.0.1    test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing below lines in the "directory" tags

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

in to this

```
Require all granted
```

fixes the issue.